# Conjecture regarding the sum of prime factors of $x!$ and $(x-1)!$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, conjectures

I think using dodgy means I can show the following:

Let $\lambda(x)$ be the sum of  primes in $x$. For example:

$$ \lambda(2) = 2$$
$$ \lambda(4) = 2 + 2 = 4$$
$$ \lambda(6) = 3 + 2 = 5$$

Then for large $n$:

$$ \frac{\lambda (n!)}{\lambda ((n-1)!)} \sim \frac{\ln (n!)}{\ln (n-1)!}$$

Or more precisely substracting $1$:

$$ \frac{\lambda (n)}{\lambda ((n-1)!)} \sim \frac{\ln (n)}{\ln (n-1)!}$$

Or even better:

$$ \frac{\lambda (n)}{\lambda ((n-1)!)} - \frac{\ln (n)}{\ln (n-1)!} = o(1)$$

Can someone prove or disprove this conjecture?

For example:

$$ \frac{\lambda(8!)}{\lambda(7!)} = \frac{31}{26} \approx 1.23$$

And

$$ \frac{\ln(8!)}{\ln(7!)} \approx 1.244 $$

Substracting $1$:

$$ .23  \approx .24$$

Comment: When you have: $$ \frac{\lambda(8!)}{\lambda(7!)} = \frac{31}{25} $$ you simplified the fraction right?

Comment: @StanislasCASTELLANA $\lambda(2) = 2$, $\lambda(3) = 3$, $\lambda(4) = 4$, $\lambda(5) = 5$ ,$\lambda(6) = 5$, $\lambda(7) = 7$, $\lambda(8) = 6$. Adding it all together one gets $\lambda(8!) = 31$ and  $\lambda(7!) = 25$

Comment: @MoreAnonymous I think you can't do that. Because first you compute $8!$ then you find the sum of primes up to that number. I might not be understanding the function properly?

Comment: @StanislasCASTELLANA Convince yourself $\lambda(y) + \lambda(z) = \lambda(yz)$

Comment: This is sequence [A001414](https://oeis.org/A001414). And [related](http://m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2012/53-56-2012/jakimczukIMF53-56-2012-2.pdf).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire cool! Interestingly I don't see my result there so does that mean if correct I've done something new? Just saw the related ... Any idea whose result is stronger? (I can increase my bound a bit)

Comment: MoreAnonymous, it looks like Theorem 2.9 in @TheSimpliFire 's "related" link says $$\lambda(n!)\sim{\pi^2\over12}{n^2\over\log n}$$ which should answer your question. (That paper refers to http://www.m-hikari.com/imf-password2008/25-28-2008/jakimczukIMF25-28-2008-2.pdf where the proof can be found.)

Comment: @BarryCipra missed that ...  I'm a bit brain dead but it seems mine is the superior bound?

Comment: @MoreAnonymous, what exactly are you claiming to be a superior "bound?" I only see the asymptotic equality symbol $\sim$ here. That's not a bound.

Comment: @BarryCipra sorry I meant better asymptote (its smaller than his) ... Also I've gone about my dodgy calculations a very different way than his D:

Comment: @TheSimpliFire mine seems to apply for smaller $n$ to the answer better than his... $\lambda(8!) \sim \frac{\pi}{12} \frac{8^2}{\ln 8} \approx  25 \neq 31$

Comment: @MoreAnonymous, ah, I think I see what you're getting at.  Both $\lambda(n!)/\lambda((n-1)!)$ and $\ln(n!)/\ln((n-1)!)$ tend to $1$ as $n\to\infty$, but it looks like you want to say their difference tends *rapidly* to $0$, or something like that.

Comment: @BarryCipra  So basically I've done a physics degree so maybe I'm not using the right notation but would to me the above is equivalent to $\frac{\lambda( n)}{\lambda (n-1)!} \sim \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n-1)!}$ and yes their difference should rapidly approach $0$

Comment: $8!=2^7\cdot3^2\cdot5^1\cdot7^1$, so it would seem that $\lambda(8!)=7\cdot2+2\cdot3+1\cdot5+1\cdot7=32$, no? Likewise, $\lambda(7!)=26$ by my calculation.

Comment: @robjohn yes your right let me correct it to $1.28$

Comment: $\frac{32}{26}=1.23076923\dots$

Comment: @MoreAnonymous, mathematicians (and number theorists especially) are very fussy about the precise meaning of approximations, and expect careful definitions somewhere along the line (preferably at the outset!). The Prime Number Theorem, $\pi(x)\sim Li(x)$, for example, means the ratio $\pi(x)/Li(x)$ tends to $1$ as $x\to\infty$, which is already a deep result, but there is an even deeper theory (involving the Riemann Hypothesis) regarding bounds on the difference, $|\pi(x)-Li(x)|$.

Comment: @BarryCipra My bad let me slog a bit more and try to include an error term as well in that case :) Also how does one show $|A-B| \to 0$ for large $N$. As in whats the correct notation?

Comment: You could write $\lim_{N\to\infty}(A-B)=0$. Or, $A-B={\rm o}(1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not make sense, why ?

**First** $ \frac{\lambda((n+1)!)}{\lambda(n!)} \sim \frac{\ln((n+1)!}{\ln n!} \implies \frac{\lambda((n+1)!)}{\lambda(n!)}\sim 1 $ but this is not that impressive, it only means that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have that $ (1-\epsilon)^n < \lambda(n!) < (1+\epsilon)^n$ for large enough $n$ (so basically $ \lambda(n!)$ grows sub-exponential), for instance i could easily said that :$$ \frac{\lambda((n+1)!)}{\lambda(n!)} \sim \frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}$$

**Second** $ \frac{\lambda(n+1)}{\lambda(n!)} \sim \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n!}$ is simply wrong take $n$ such that $ n+1$ is prime number and so $ \lambda(n+1) = n+1$  and $ \lambda (n!) \sim \frac{\pi^2 n^2}{12 \ln n}$ and $\ln n! \sim n \ln n$ and so what you are saying is that $ \frac{12 \ln n}{\pi^2 n} \sim \frac{1}{n}$ which obviously is not correct.

**Third** This part tells you nothing simply because $ \frac{\lambda(n+1)}{\lambda(n!)} = o(1)$ so i could easily said that : $$ \frac{\lambda(n+1)}{\lambda(n!)} - \frac{1}{\ln \ln n} = o(1)$$

Also the function $\lambda(n)$ is very **chaotic** as most of the arithmetic function in number theory because they are related to the prime numbers and those guys are the definition of chaotic in small intervals( for instance when $n+1$ is highly composite number $\frac{\lambda(n+1)}{\lambda(n!)}$ will approach $0$ waaay faster than if $n+1$ was prime number).

In these cases we find the **Average\Sum** of such function to have beautiful results such as $ \lambda (n!) \sim \frac{\pi^2 n^2}{12 \ln n}$.

Hope its helpfull.